# What is the single highest rate of fire weapon in bf4?

Tags: battlefield-4

Is it the famas? or one of the engeneer weapons? what weapon in bf4 has the highest rounds per minute?

Comment: 93r and g18, for pistols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAMAS and CZ-3A1 are tied for the highest rate of fire. Both fire 1000 rounds per minute, though this doesn't take reloading into account.

Source: [Symthic](http://symthic.com/bf4-weapon-charts?secondaries=1&allkcarbine=1&allkdmr=1&support=1&recon=1&assault=1&engineer=1&sort=Rate%20of%20Fire&adsc=DESC)

Answer (score 2):

The famas is one of the 2 fastest weapons in the game, beside to the CZ-3A1 wich both fire at 1000rpm.

The fastest PDW is the CZ-3A1.

If you are looking for a awesome CQC-Dominator, i recommend you the MTAR-21. It's far more controllable. It comes "only" with 900rpm (wich still is insane) but has a balanced spread (0.42;0.42,0.34) (left/right/up) and lower first-shot multiplyer (2,8) than the CZ-3A1 which comes with (0.30;0.55;0.40) and (3,3).

Let's compare MTAR-21 with CZ-3A1:

```
RECOIL per shot
     left /right /  up
MTAR 0.42 / 0.42 / 0.34
CZ   0.30 / 0.55 / 0.40
```

This means, the MTAR has a higher recoil in general but it spreads in all directions while CZ mainly to the upper right, which makes it really hard to controll.
Also, this is per shot. CZ has >10 more rpm which means if you want to know the recoil over fullauto time, you have to multiply the CZ Recoil by 1,11 (1000/900)

```
SPREAD
    standing / walking
MTAR   0.35     0.625
CZ     0.4      0.6
```

So the MTAR has a 12,5% lower spread while standing still, and the CZ a ~4% lower spread while walking. CQC is mostly walking, but the 4% aren't a lot, 12,5% is.

SPREAD increase per shot
   MTAR -> 1.117
   CZ   -> 1.3

This tells everything. Even if the CZ has better spread on first look, this only lasts for 2 shots (ignoring first shot, which is negated by first-shot multiplier).

In the end, also the MTARs spread lowers 10% faster after shoting, which makes it a better for micro-busting than the CZ.

CZ really has the better rate of fire, but thats all. In any other handlingstatistics, MTAR is better and this is what practice has told me too. Awesome weapon for CQC.

Comment: Uhhh nevermind. The fastest weapon is the 20mm vulcan. 2000rpm, famas on meth.

Answer (score -1):

AN-94 in full-auto is one of the slowest, with only 600 RPM, but has a 2-round burst mode with 1200 RPM. That's the highest rate of fire of any gun in the game.

Comment: The AN-94 has 1200RPM/per burst with a delay of 120ms (source is reddit) between each burst. Due one burst fires 3 rounds, you shot 10 bursts per mag. This means you get a total delay of 1200ms per mag. Clearing a mag should take 1/20 of a minute without delay. (1200/30) so we got 20 times the full mag-delay to substract from the RPM. 20*1,2 = 24Secs. So the AN-94(without reloading) is only shooting 36 seconds, not a minute. This means, the gross RPM in burst(without reloading) is 720RPM, not 1200.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you'd try to empty whole mag of CZ-3A1, it'll go all over the place. You are going to burst fire anyway if you want any kind of accuracy. Question is about RPM, not about CQC sprayer for noobs.

Comment: My top 3 weapons in 600hrs of bf4 are mtar, cz and famas. So i got a decent feel for the handling of high rpm weapons. In the end its a matter of how many bullets hit the enemy in a couple hundrets of miliseconds. If there is a delay of over 100ms within every burst, you git a huge disadvantage in cqb. I assume that if two players at same skill would have 100 contacts in cqb, a famas, mtar or cz player would kill the 94 player in at least 75 times. An 94 is a awesome midrage weapon with decent capability for far and close range, but its far from beeing the cqb ruler.

Comment: The AN94 is nice, because you CAN win at close range where other mid to high range, as aug or m16, would loose almost guaranteed. But i would never choose it as a cqb ruler.

Comment: Question is about RPM, not best CQB weapon. Besides, in CQB any shotgun with explosive ammo would kill you before you'd get a chance to peek around the corner :-P

Comment: Okay then, only correct answer is the Vulcan 20mm. 2000rpm.